# Pass a argument to Django meta class

Tags: python, django

I can alternatively create different types of form, but that's tedious.
So is it possible to pass the type to the form,then show the form accordingly?
This code shows `NameError: name 'review_type' is not defined`

```
class Contest1_for_review(ModelForm, review_type):

    class Meta:

        model = Contest1

        decision = review_type + '_decision'
        comment = review_type +'comment'

        fields = [
            decision,
            comment,
        ]
```

Is it possible to pass a argument to meta class, like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form is a class and when its rendered in the HTML, its rendering an instance of the form class. So when passing a value to that instance, you can use its `__init__` method. For example:

```
class Contest1_for_review(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        review_type = kwargs.pop('review_type')  # <-- getting the value from keyword arguments
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields[f'{review_type}_decision'] = forms.CharField()
        self.fields[f'{review_type}_comment'] = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Contest1
        fields = "__all__"
```

Also, you need to send the value of `review_type` from view to form. Like this in function based view:

```
form = Contest1_for_review(review_type="my_value")
```

Or use [**`get_form_kwargs`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs) to send the value from a Class based view. FYI: you don't need to change anything in **Meta** class.

---

Update:

From discussion in comments, OP should use `forms.Form` instead of `ModelForm` as using model form requires fields /exclude value in `Meta` class.

Comment: I got ```django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form Contest1_for_review needs updating.``` this error. After adding this ```fields = "__all__"```, it worked. But it will show all the fields in this model, so is there any other solution?

Comment: Then you should use a `forms.Form` instead of `ModelForm`

Comment: Thank you so much !!! Your suggestion solve my problem perfectly. And I realize how to use a form.